# FetchType EAGER is not the same as Root fetch()?

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

I'm working on building a query using JPA 2 CriteriaBuilder using Hibernate 4 as my provider.  I've been playing around with FetchModes and have concluded that SELECT is the one I need. But SELECT forces enables FetchType.LAZY. I read this somewhere and that seems to be the case.

In the Devices class this configuration produces the right result:

```
@Fetch(value=FetchMode.SELECT)
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "device")
public List<DevInterfaces> getDevInterfaces() {
    return this.devInterfaces;
}
```

However I do not want FetchType=EAGER hard-coded in my entity.  I want to control when the fetch occurs and I thought I could do it with a fetch() like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Devices> dq = cb.createQuery(Devices.class);
Root<Devices> dev = dq.from(Devices.class);
dev.fetch(Devices_.devInterfaces)
```

but the result is an inner join and I don't want that.

How do I fetch with FetchMode.SELECT without hard-coding FetchType.EAGER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in question, and as also documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/FetchParent.html#fetch%28javax.persistence.metamodel.PluralAttribute%29), `fetch` uses inner join.

Join type can be specified when using overloaded fetch method that takes also [JoinType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/JoinType.html) as an argument:

```
dev.fetch(Devices_.devInterfaces, JoinType.LEFT)
```